# Azure web app configuration for MP4

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

There seems to be a strange problem with my Azure webapp. I can't view MP4 files on my browser at all. After exploring few articles here, I did the following:
I use Github continuous deployment, so I created a new file called "Web.config". The content of it is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
            <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
            <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
            <remove fileExtension=".mp4" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml"  />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I made sure on the FTP that the file exists in the '/site/wwwroot' directory, and it does. I also made sure the MP4 file exists on the FTP in an accessible location.

The error I get on the website is the following:

> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name
>   changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

Can anyone help me debug this problem?

Comment: Note: I did set a virtual application and directories setting from:
\
To: site\wwwroot\www

(The website itself works)

Comment: Where is the web.config file and where is the .mp4 file?

Comment: @BenjaminTalmard /site/wwwroot/Web.config
/site/wwwroot/www/img/wallpapers/video-background-4.mp4

Comment: Can you try to move the Web.config to /site/wwwroot/www ?

Comment: @BenjaminTalmard It worked! thanks.

Comment: Great ! I've tried to summarize our discussion and to add a reference in an answer below. If it helped, please validate it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following our discussion, your web.config is right.
You have to make sure to locate it in the right location to make it works (the virtual application root in your case).

As Azure App Service is using IIS, you can find more details regarding IIS configuration files here: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/deep-dive-into-iis-configuration-with-iis-7-and-iis-8

I hope this helps,